# Where to find host name or IP for Seleniumwire

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-grid, seleniumwire

I'm trying to run seleniumwire driver in the remote mode. The issue is that I don't quite understand some instructions from the official docs: https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#all-options

```
options = {
    'addr': 'hostname_or_ip'  # Address of the machine running Selenium Wire. Explicitly use 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost if remote session is running locally.
}
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://www.example.com',
    seleniumwire_options=options
)
```

Where do I find the hostname of IP?
At first I thought it might be the address I use for connecting to the selenium grid, something like this 'http://hub.selenium-grid:4444/wd/hub'. But it raised an error:

```
E   seleniumwire.thirdparty.mitmproxy.exceptions.ServerException: Error starting proxy server: gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')
```

So, if it's not the correct 'addr', what should I use instead?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:
https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/issues/327
it works for me when i use real ip, not 127.0.0.1
i hope it will be useful to you

my code(the port 9922 is arbitrary ,as long as the port is not in use):

```
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=192.168.64.131:9922')
    seleniumwire_options = {
        'suppress_connection_errors': False,
        'auto_config': True,
        'addr': '192.168.64.131',
        'port': 9922
    }
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://192.168.64.131:4444/wd/hub",
        desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities(),
        seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options
    )
```